# Why our community doesn't have a logo?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

Most of the communities in [Stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) have dedicated logos.

But why don't we have one?

Comment: @user4168 answered this question well. But your question is a good one. Maybe someday. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the contrary, most of SE sites do not have a designed logo, as you can see by browsing [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest).

The post [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614) outlines the process by which a site may acquire a custom design.

1. The site consistently gets at least 10 questions per day.
2. The Community Team considers some less quantifiable factors in deciding whether the site is ready to graduate; in particular, there should be enough engaged users to support a meaningful competitive election for 3 moderator positions.
3. After the site graduates, it joins the queue of sites waiting for a custom design. There are currently [10 sites in the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326798).

Items 2-3 only become relevant after step 1.  Amateur Radio currently gets about 2 questions per day.